# Small YAML/JSON parser in C

Tags: c, json, yaml, c99

I've been looking for a small YAML/JSON parser, preferably a single-file solution, so i can easily embed it on my application. I'm looking for a small and simple solution since i intend to use it on different platforms, and building libyaml and other solutions will be a huge pain in the ass.

Also, is TinyXML a good alternative? What is fastest to parse?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was looking for something similar sometime last year.  This is the one I settled on:
[YAJL](http://lloyd.github.io/yajl/)

It's not a single file solution, but it's not very big either.  I has some features like JSON formatting and syntax checking that you might see as feature bloat, but they don't bother me.

Comment: I tried http://www.digip.org/jansson, it has a very nice API that i would love to see in any YAML parser.